# MS Excel formula for =IF(OR with date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

[image]

Hi, My question is about Excel formula, I need help in making a formula where in the date from another worksheet should appear "20" or "4" (on another worksheet)based either it's a past or a future date. e.g date today is september 30 2019, if it's <= it should appear as "4", else should be 20. I uploaded some screenshot to better understand the question, it's a bit hard for me to explain it, but I hope someone gets it and show me how it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: remove the `or(`

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it working now. Cheers

Comment: @Cee,, no  need to put OR ,, it should simple as ,, `=IF(SheetName!E2<DATE(2019,9,27),4,20)` ☺

Answer (score 0):

Since you left the only clue to your current formula in an image, I'll address your narrative (which doesn't match your image).

You're not accounting for the time portion of the value in the *Status Date/Time* column. Time is a fraction of a day so you cannot calculate `<=` a date unless you actually calculate `<` tomorrow.

September 30, 2019 03:00 pm is **not** `<=` September 30, 2019. However, September 30, 2019 03:00 pm **is** `<` October 1, 2019. The formula would be better as,

```
=IF(blah-blah-blah.csv!$E2 < DATE(2019, 10, 1), 4, 20)
'alternate
=4 + (blah-blah-blah.csv!$E2 >= DATE(2019, 10, 1))*16
```